# Firefox 36 doesn't play mp3s on our site after update

Tags: firefox, audio, mp3

since FF36 on windows, the mp3s on one of our websites don't play anymore. They worked fine in previous version of Firefox ... they still play on all other major browsers, and even FF36 for Mac, but not on FF36 for windows.

Firefox simply claims that the mp3 is corrupt, but Checkmate Validator says it's fine.

Funny thing is, the mp3s work again after re-encoding with Audacity (with no change in settings) but we don't really want to re-encode our whole library if we don't absolutely have to.

Here's a link to an offending mp3: http://www.calvaryem.org/wp-content/uploads/mp3/20150315AM.mp3

And here's a link to the re-encoded mp3 with Audacity (same settings): http://www.calvaryem.org/wp-content/uploads/mp3/20150315AM-stereo.mp3

Though the mp3s are slightly different, MP3 validators claim that both mp3s are valid.

Any idea why these mp3s are different, and whether its a Firefox glitch or a glitch with our mp3s?

Comment: 1st link - "video can't be played because the file is corrupt" 2nd link - plays fine (Firefox 36.0.1, Windows 64 bit)

Comment: Yep ... that's the issue. The first one is the original mp3, the second one is it re-encoded (with no changes) in audacity. Trying to figure out why there's a difference ...

Comment: The solution is obvious. Re-encode all the files. Why do you expect that we have a different solution if it seems obvious? Telling you why is primarily opinion based which is off-topic for SuperUser anyway.

Comment: Regardless of any answer here you should open a bug with Mozilla https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/

Comment: LPChip - good point. Just thought someone else might have had this problem, and we could possibly avoid that painful step if it turned out to be a firefox bug instead of a bug on our end. David-thanks, will do that.